# DH61AG's mythical 2 pin 19v power socket and is too low of votage bad?

Tags: power-supply, power

I have an intel dh61ag motherboard.  It has an external 19v power adapter.  It also has a 1x2 pin 19VDC internal power connector.  Now I cannot find a psu or adapter or anything that will plug into this.  In an intel forum, one person said that he plugged half of a 2x2 psu connector in and it worked.  Since this would deliver 12v into a socket that asks for 19v, I suspect that this is a bad idea.  I don't know much about hardware.  Can anyone explain to me why this would be a bad idea?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot (or don't want to) use the standard DC input on the back panel? A suitable adapter for that should be much easier to find than a desktop power supply that has a 19 V output.

Comment: I currently use it, but I'd like to be able to use an internal psu to save space.

Comment: Could you not mount that external adapter in the same space you'd be using for the internal PSU? Also, I added an answer to your question with regards to using 12 V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feed 12 V into a system that expects 19 V, then the most likely outcome is that the system will fail to start. There shouldn't be any hardware damage, though, unlike if you were to provide too high a voltage.

Since 19 V is not among the voltages that the [ATX standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Power_supply) specifies, you'll have a hard time finding a power supply that provides 19 V. I'm not aware of any that exist. A quick online search revealed only laptop-style power adapters that plug into the rear panel DC input.

Update: I did find a suitable connector that fits the 1x2 on the motherboard that you could use to rig up your own power cable: http://www.alliedelec.com/search/productdetail.aspx?SKU=70190678
That still requires a power supply with a 19 V output, however. Or, if you do decide to mount your existing power adapter internally and can't use the rear panel DC input (due to space constraints, for example), you could replace the adapter's barrel connector with this one. Note you'll also need some matching [terminals](http://www.alliedelec.com/search/productdetail.aspx?SKU=70190697) for the connector.

Answer (score 3):

+19 (±10%) VDC means you can supply this board from 17,1 to 20,9V. Other voltages out of condition. Lower or higher voltages can damage your board.

Answer (score 1):

**It is 19V only. It can not be used with 12V, because it says so in doc:**

http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/dh61ag/sb/CS-032443.htm

```
2.2.3.3 Power Supply Connectors
The board has the following power supply connectors:
• External Power Supply – the board can be powered through a 19 V DC
connector on the backpanel. The backpanel DC connector is compatible with a 7.4
mm/OD (outer diameter) and 5.1 mm/ID (inner diameter) plug, where the inner
contact is +19 (±10%) V DC and the shell is GND. The maximum current rating is
12 A.
• Internal Power Supply – the board can alternatively be powered via the internal
19 V DC 1 x 2 power connector, where pin 1 is GND and
```

### **pin 2 is +19 (±10%) VDC**.

Comment: I understand that it takes 19v.  My question is what would happen if you only feed it 12.